# Writing to a Dictionary permanently

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Firstly Im not sure if this is even the best approach.

So im trying to figure out how to write to a dictionary so that the new keys and values are stored even after I terminate the program. So lets say I have:

```
mydict = {'Name':'John', 'Favourite Colour': 'Blue', 'Age':'10'}
print(mydict)

mydict['Food'] = 'Chicken'

print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'John', 'Favourite Colour': 'Blue', 'Age': '10'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Favourite Colour': 'Blue', 'Age': '10', 'Food': 'Chicken'}
```

The next time I launch this program and the `dict['Food'] = 'Chicken'`was removed. I would like food key to already be stored there. After that I would like to create another dictionary for lets say 'Bob' with these keys but give different values based on user input.

Should I start looking at making a database or is a dictionary a way of going about this?

Comment: Do not use `dict` as a variable name. `dict` is a built-in dictionary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can pickle (save into a file) your dictionary before exiting the program and then unpickle it when the program starts:

```
import os.path, pickle

SAVED = "mydict.p"
if os.path.isfile(SAVED):
    with open(SAVED, "rb") as infile:
        mydict = pickle.load(infile)
else:
    mydict = ... # Initialize the dictionary for the first time

... # Possibly change mydict here
...

with open(SAVED, "wb") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(mydict, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

i am unable to understand your 1st part of the question.

i found a simple implementation for the 2nd part to your question

```
Bob={}
Bob=dict.fromkeys(mydict)
```

The above will copy the keys from one dictionary to Bob.

```
for key,val in Bob.items():
    Bob[key]=input()
```

Above code inputs the values for the copied keys.